# I am getting "Authentication did not succeed for user ID" repeatedly 20 times

Tags: java, websphere-7, websphere-8, websphere-liberty, apache-wink

I am using ApacheWink and WAS Liberty 8.5
When a user enters a wrong password at server console below log message is printed 20 times consecutively.

> [AUDIT   ] CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID sdwtest1@in.ibm.com. An invalid user ID or password was specified.

I debugged the client code of Apache Wink so above logs are printed when call reaches to line `java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()`

when the call returns it give the response code 401.
The `connection.getResponseCode()` call is made from the `org.apache.wink.client.internal.handlers.HttpURLConnectionHandler` class

I want that if at first attempt 401 is received it should not retry again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found this APAR related to the message,
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM65742
If you are not already running 8.5.0.1 or higher then I suggest you upgrade to see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
My current Liberty version is 8.5 Will check the issue after upgrading the Liberty.